# Integer roots to cubic equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

If I have a cubic equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, what constraints exist on $a,b,c$ when we have three integer solutions?

How do I choose $a,b,c$ to force integer solutions?

Comment: I think you should be able to recognize them using Vieta's formula for cubic equations, which states that if a cubic equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has three different roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$, then:

$$\left\{\begin{eqnarray*}
-a &=& x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
b &=& x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 \\
-c &=& x_1x_2x_3
\end{eqnarray*}\right..$$

Comment: Let $x_i$ be the roots, so $x^3+ax^2+bx+c = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3) = x^3-(x_1+x_2+x_3)x^2+(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_3)x-x_1x_2x_3$ now you can compare the coefficients and see what you get. The most important property for finding roots 'by hand' is using that $x_i|c$.

Comment: Are you asking, for example, given $b, c$ how to choose $a$ so that the roots are integers?

Answer (score 2):

- Vieta's formulas (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas)
- every root is a factor of c

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the Rational Root Theorem.