# Is Integer Solution of Cubic Negative?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, solution-verification, cubics

I have been trying to solve a problem where OP seeks [Integer roots to cubic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884705/integer-roots-to-cubic-equation/884711). There are similar problems ( see [1,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367016/integer-solutions-of-a-cubic-equation) [2,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093995/requirements-for-an-integer-root-of-cubic-equation) [3,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885694/roots-of-cubic-equation-with-integer-coefficients) [4,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068034/integer-solutions-to-cubic-equation) [5,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093995/requirements-for-an-integer-root-of-cubic-equation) [6,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170175/integral-roots-of-cubic-equation-x3-27xk-0) [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0/2157645#2157645)) in this forum.

To solve the general cubic$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0\tag{i}$$, 
Remove the $ax^2$ term by substituting $x=\dfrac {y-a}3$. Let the transformed equation be$$y^3+py+q=0\tag{ii}$$,we get a root as

$$y=\left(-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}\right)^{\frac 13}+\left(-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}\right)^{\frac 13}\tag{iii}$$

If the the root is integer then the **surds** $\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}$, and $\left(-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}\right)^{\frac 13}$ **has to be integer.** If $\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}$ is integer we can write, $\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}=c \implies \frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}=c^2$. Now, [from this post we know,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578993/integer-solution-to-x3y2-z2) that if $p/3=n$ and $q=n(n-1)$ then $\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}$ is an integer, then we get-

$$y=n^{\frac13}-(n^2)^{\frac13}$$

If we substitute $n=n_1^3$, then we get, $y=n_1-n_1^2$, which is a negative number.

**Is it a correct solution? Is the integer solution of a cubic always negative? This seems not to be true, but then what am I missing?**

**If this solution is correct but gives some integer solution, then , how we get all the integer solutions of cubic putting constrain on $p,q$ like  $p/3=n$ and $q=n(n-1)$? Note, $p, q$ are nonzero.**

Comment: The integer solution of a cubic is not always negative.  For example ${{x}^{3}}-2{{x}^{2}}-2 x+4=0$ has one integer root and it is positive

Answer (score 0):

1. "If the root is integer, then the surds... has to be integer"  This is not correct.  The irrational parts could cancel out, leaving an integer.  Try $p=0$, $q=-1$.
2. The case $p/3 = n$ and $q = n(n-1)$ considered in the other post is not representative of all cubics, only that particular family of cubics. So I don't see how you can draw the conclusion "integer solution of a cubic [is] always negative."

Comment: $p=0$, $q=-1$ seems to be trivial case, consider nonzero $p, q$, can give us an example then?

Comment: If $p=3n,q=n(n-1)$ gives an integer for the square root, then do does $p=3n,q=-n(n-1)$; and the sign change on $1$ reverses the signs of all roots.

Comment: @Andrew Take any 3 integers a,b,c that sum to 0, let $p = ab+bc+ac$ and $q = -abc$.  Then the roots of the cubic will be the integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and with almost any case you try, the $\sqrt{q^2/4 + p^3/27}$ will not be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly untrue as the cubic equation $x^3=0$ has a nonnegative integral root. In general, for any three integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $c\geq0$ the cubic equation
$$(x^2+ax+b)(x-c)=0,$$
has a nonnegative integral root. As noted in Andrews answer, your argument fails when you claim that the surds must be integers; the two algebraic numbers
$$\left\{-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\left\{-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4+\frac {p^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13},$$
can very well both be irrational and still sum to an integer.

To find integral roots of rational cubic equations, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) is very effective in determining whether an integral solution exists. As far as I know, there is no algebraic invariant of the cubic that determines whether the cubic has an integral root.

Comment: It does not help much, if $a/b, b/a, 1$ are there roots, then the last constant term will be 1, and there is no way to no that by factoring that term...

Comment: @Andrew Have you bothered to look what the coefficients of that polynomial are?